# How can I access table rows from multithreaded application without locking?

Tags: mysql, multithreading, database-design, spring-data-jpa, architecture

I'm developing an application with table that contains data about something.
Now, I want refresh some rows in that table based on column "RefreshMe".

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `datatable` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `row_created` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `row_modified` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `refresh_me` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `refresh_date` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `next_refresh_date` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `refresh_days` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `version` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

If RefreshMe is true that row should be refreshed.

The question is: **How can I select rows from that table from multithreaded application with minimum collisions?**

I don't want to use `select for update` for that task. Just use optimistic locks (spring jpa).

If I just use `select * from datatable where refresh_me = 1 order by row_modified asc;` then threads will get same rows and should resolve optimistic locks.

The only method I can imagine is selecting 100 rows, taking 10 random rows and work with them. That should decrease conflicts between 2-10 running threads.

How to solve that task for 100 threads?
**Is there any better way to do that?**

Comment: Why are you excluding the best and simplest way to achieve the goal -- with `FOR UPDATE`?

Comment: Refresh of data takes time, so I just want to be sure that no other treads doing same job.

Comment: If the work takes more than a few seconds, let's talk about a different way to 'process' an item.  Did you try picking just one at a time?  No 100 random, n0 10.

Answer (score 1):

"Multithreads" is a lot of processes which refreshes the rows?

If so then I recommend you to use pre-reserving.

Alter `refresh_me` to BIGINT UNSIGNED NULL.

Accept the following values:

- NULL - does not need to be refreshed,
- 0 - need to be refreshed, not reserved,
- other values - CONNECTION_ID() of the thread connection which reserves this row for refreshing.

When the row must be refreshed then its `refresh_me` is set to 0.

The thread which must refresh rows reserves needed rows amount for refreshing with

```
UPDATE datatable
SET refresh_me = CONNECTION_ID()
WHERE refresh_me = 0
-- ORDER BY ...
LIMIT NNN;
```

If the amount of effected rows is zero then there are no rows which needes in refreshing, and the thread may exit or sleep.

Then it processes reserved rows (their amount can be less than specified NNN value due to concurrent threads interference) one-by-one with

```
-- get one reserved row
SELECT *
FROM datatable
WHERE refresh_me = CONNECTION_ID()
LIMIT 1;

-- process selected row identified by its PK value using SQL and/or application code
...

-- save new data state
UPDATE datatable
SET ...
WHERE primary_key_column = ...;
```

Reserved rows are iterated until the next iteration does not return reserved row (i.e. all reserved rows are already processed). In this case the next rows chunk is reserved.

---

Using this pre-reserving there makes no sense to reserve a lot of rows. You may reserve only one row (i.e. use LIMIT 1) then either process it or, if the row was re-reserved by the concurrent thread (further SELECT after UPDATE LIMIT 1 does not return the row), repeat the attempt to reserve the row.

---

It is possible that the thread hangs/fails. So I recommend you to add autoutilized `updated_at` column, and create an event procedure which checks for rows which are reserved but the time elapsed from the reserving timepoint is too high, and returns such rows to the rows pool which needs in refreshing with simple

```
UPDATE datatable 
SET refresh_me = 0 
WHERE refresh_me 
  AND updated_at < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL NNN SECOND;
```

Comment: I think that's a good solution, thanks!

Comment: Also, be sure to have `INDEX(refresh_me, row_modified, id)`.